# C++ giving me basic_string::_S_construct null not valid error after I run my program

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to C++ and I've tried to write a simple string reverse program. When I compile it, everything is OK, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What I am doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string reverse_string(char* argv[], int i);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        cout << reverse_string(argv, i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

string reverse_string(char* argv[], int i)
{
    string arg = argv[i + 1];
    string output;
    int length = arg.length();
    for (int index = 1; index <= length; index++)
    {
        output += arg[length-index];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You are assigning a nullptr to string which is invalid, most likely it is `argv[i+1]`. See it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6abd8a3807f8a528).

Comment: The error is because you are attempting to construct an `std::string` from a null `char*` at some point.

Comment: `argv[argc]`, which happens on your last iteration, is a null pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This: `argv[i + 1]` in the construction of your reversed string should be `argv[i]` and the main loop should be `for (i=1; i<argc; ++i)`

And there are simpler ways to reverse a string:

```
std::string reverse_string(char* argv[], int i)
{
    std::string arg = argv[i];
    return std::string(arg.rbegin(), arg.rend());
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've noticed this already. And thanks for the simpler way :).

Answer (score 2):

This error message

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>   what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

means that you are trying to call constructor of std::string passing as argument pointer NULL. The problem is that `*(argv + argc)` is NULL pointer.

Also take into account that you must include header `<string>`

As for the reverse function then it can be written much simpler then that of you. First of all it could have only one parameter of type `const char *`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string reverse_string( const char* s );

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        std::cout << argv[i] << " -> " << reverse_string( argv[i] ) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

std::string reverse_string( const char* s )
{
    std::string arg( s );
    return std::string( arg.rbegin(), arg.rend() );
}
```

Comment: One note: `argv + argc` cannot be a null pointer because `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be a null pointer.

Comment: @chris It is a typo. Shall be *(argv + argc )

Comment: Yep, I understood that already. And about `const char* s`, I am still learning :). So thats why I din't use `const char*`

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks for help everyone! I just didn't want to reverse argument 0, which is program's name. But I found another way around it. If anyone is interested, here is the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string reverse_string(char* argv[], int i);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        cout << argv[i] << " -> " << reverse_string(argv, i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

string reverse_string(char* argv[], int i)
{
    string arg = argv[i];
    string output;
    int length = arg.length();
    for (int index = 1; index <= length; index++)
    {
        output += arg[length-index];
    }
    return output;
}
```